# How to store Whole index path, previous,before previous and current selected index path value to the NSArray within didSelectRowAtIndexPath: methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios7

Problem :

I develop Quiz apps. In the apps there are like 5 questions in one tableview. Questions are taken from a plist file. Whenever I have selected the questions choice in the tableview it is showing the current selected index_path value.

But I want all the question choices like from 1 to 5 selected index_path in the array.

My Code :

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // what is that code,....?

}
```

I want:

```
NSLog(@"whole index_path : %@",array name);
```

output:

> whole index_path : 
>   0
>   1
>   0
>   2
>   1

Comment: ALL questions are in ONE tableview? or are they shown one after another?

Comment: Single Table view,but i have use itself segue means,get the question from plist if select one quiz choices it will navigate next questions in same tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. you have to do three things:

1. go to your storyboard and give the segue from the resultsviewcontroller to the analysisviewcontroller an identifier "AnalysisScreen"
2. go to your resultsviewcontroller.m and implement the following method:

`- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AnalysisScreen"]) {
        AnalysisViewController *analysisViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        analysisViewController.currentQuiz = self.currentQuiz;
    }
}`

3. go to your analysisviewcontroller.m and in cellForItemAtIndexPath replace the line

`Quizcell.TotalQuestions.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`

with the following lines:

`Question *question = self.currentQuiz[indexPath.row];
 Quizcell.TotalQuestions.backgroundColor = (question.selectedResponse == question.correctResponse) ? [UIColor greenColor] : [UIColor redColor];`

hope i got you right! :)

Comment: I tried but i got                                                                                            2015-05-06 18:23:39.619IQ[38228:2439606] Total_Index : (
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000008056> { length = 2, path = 1 - 1 }"
)                                                                                                                          it showing last selected index_path but i wants whole selected index_path

Comment: ,i didnt get error its showing last selected index_path value only.

Comment: would you like to share your project so i can take a better look at whats going wrong?

Comment: ok, i tried your project. now what exactly is the problem? :)

Comment: in apps there are 3 questions .i want end of result view one option is there Analysis.if u click its showing how many questions are there like that. i want the collection view cell would show how many questions could be right and wrong intimate by red(wrong)/green(right)

Comment: but if i understand your model correctly you are already tracking the users responses. you have the *selectedresponse* and the *correctresponse*. with that information you can show the green / red indicators in your collection view, can't you?

Comment: i do not understand your question :)

Comment: Nope....Broooo ur awsssssm....i got ur answer.that could work perfectly.Thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `NSMutableArray` and add `index paths` as objects. Whenever you are showing a question like if it's first question access its object from array and see which index path is selected and set that row as selected, and similarly for other questions.

But I would suggest you that rather than keeping index paths in array create a `NSObject` class with `question id, selected answer id` as members and when you are showing a question for which the user has selected something earlier than access the `selected answer id` and show that as selected.

Comment: Could u post any examples for in this problems.

Comment: ,Ur rt but i newbie in iOS .so only i asked

Comment: @Tamil_Arya I have posted another answer, you can use the approach of the same for your implementation.

Comment: I tried but i got error only becz ur method would be hard for me.Thanks for that.i would post my project can u help me?

Comment: @Tamil_Arya have you seen my another answer on the same page below?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have 5 questions, and each question can have max 5 options.

You have a screen with a table view, you show 1 question with there options (2 - 5 rows) in table view at a time, you would have some option for the user to navigate to next questions (in that case you reload the table with next question)

This is your set up.

Now, as per my suggestion create a NSObject class to keep information for the selected option for each question.

```
@interface CustomObject : NSObject 
{
    NSInteger   _questionId;
    NSInteger   _answerId;
}
@property (nonatomic,readwrite,assign) NSInteger questionId;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite,assign) NSInteger answerId;

@end

#import "CustomObject.h”

@implementation CustomObject

@synthesize questionId = _questionId, answerId = _answerId;

-(id) initWithQuestionId:(NSUInteger)qId answerId:(NSUInteger)aId
{
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {
        _questionId = qId;
        _answerId = aId;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Now suppose for the 5 questions you have the `id’s` as `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and initially no answer is selected so keep a non applicable id for `selected answer id` as `-1`.

Create a `NSMutableArray` inside your class showing table view as

```
NSMutableArray *m_selectedAnsInfoList;
```

initialize above array once as

```
m_selectedAnsInfoList = [NSMuatbleArray alloc] init];
```

initially create object of CustomObject class for each question as

(suppose we have `5 question` so `questionCount = 5`)

```
for (int i=1; i <= questionCount : i++)// will iterate for 5 times
{     
      //create instance of CustomObject with current iteration count as question id and 
      // initially -1 for answer id, as for the first time no answer will be selected
      CustomObject *obj = [[CustomObject alloc] initWithQuestionId:i answerId:-1];
     // add object to the array
     [m_selectedAnsInfoList addObject:obj];
     [obj release];
}
```

You create table view with showing answers as rows for a question, initially you will show all the rows as unselected.

inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
     // currentQuestionId keeps id of the table view showing current question
     // using which access the questionInfoObject
     obj = [m_selectedAnsInfoList objectAtIndex:currentQuestionId];
     //  set answer id in object
     obj.answerId = indexPath.row; (from 0 to (number of answers - 1));
     // replace old object with updated obj in array as
     [m_selectedAnsInfoList replaceObject:obj atIndex:currentQuestionId];
}
```

In this way you store the information of the answers selected for each question and show them selected based on the information stored in the corresponding object in list.